# Human Following Robot with NAV2

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-humble, nav2, usb-camera

I am Currently work on making my robot to Follow a human using USB camera with ROS2 humble. My aim is to use [Dynamic Object Following](https://navigation.ros.org/tutorials/docs/navigation2_dynamic_point_following.html) in NAV2 .

But , for the detection of human I need to make app to send the initial pose to the *NavigateToPose* action,and update it on a topic for the duration of the task.

Can anyone suggest me **Follow Pose App** to achieve this. I think as an App they mention about a ROS2 package.  Does anyone use above method to follow a human? if yes , can you briefly describe the steps that you followed?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.